# Fontify source code blocks with Org 9.0

Tags: org-mode, font-lock

Is there a way to do syntax highlighting in `org-mode` code blocks without using: `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)`?

Since v. 8, I have been unable to fontify the background for `org-block` with this option enabled.
Would love to fontify my code blocks though!

Comment: Since Org 9 `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` and a background color with `org-block` work for me. It didn't work in org 8, but it was fixed with [this patch](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/81af689d0f214c98c9bd45f482f18329c5e84ca1) for org 9.

Comment: Ah, your right. I just needed to update my packages on Elpa. All good now, thank!

Answer (score 1):

This was a hold-over from version 8. The solution was to simply update my `org` packages on elpa: `M-x list-packages`. Then move the cursor to (in my case) to `org-plus-contrib` and hit `U` to mark for updating and `x` to execute.

Restart Emacs and it should be all good.